# Array values split over multiple, random and unique array entries between two numbers in PHP

Tags: php

I have generated an array with (n) random, unique values (cols) between the numbers 0 and 1080. I now need to insert these values randomly over x keys (rows). Those rows also need to be random and unique, and between "0" and "1880".

So, if I for example have 8 random values between 0 and 1080

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 94 
    [1] => 337 
    [2] => 601 
    [3] => 751 
    [4] => 793 
    [5] => 864 
    [6] => 923 
    [7] => 1047 
)
```

I need these to be values of keys unique and randomly picked between 0, 1880 like below:

```
Array ( 
    [5] => 94 
    [105] => 337 
    [621] => 601 
    [827] => 751 
    [852] => 793 
    [1087] => 864 
    [1310] => 923 
    [1781] => 1047 
)
```

If the amount of values is greater than the amount of available keys (0-1800), I need these keys to instead hold an array of values, split randomly over the entries.

Example: (5 unique random values (cols) between 0 - 20) and (3 random keys (rows) between 0 - 10)

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 4
    ) 
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 15
    ) 
    [7] => 18 
)
```

I've figured how make this in JavaScript, but I'm not sure how I'd translate it into PHP. I also feel like the "random function" could use some improvement, as it now may result in a close to infinite loop.

jsbin can [be found here](http://jsbin.com/wayaxesa/1/edit).

Comment: Are `array(15 => 15)` (duplicated key and value) , `array(15 => 21, 18 => 21)` (duplicated 2 values) allowed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can iterate and generate your array:
    (use a while loop, otherwhise you may generate the same key twice, and end with an array of length n-1)

```
$m = 3;
$n = 10;

$tmp_array =  array();
while (count($tmp_array)< $n){ //ensures unique keys, upto 10. NOTE: don't do this for large n's, it might take serious amount of time - for n > 1800 it'll never stop!
  $tmp_array[mt_rand(0,1800)] = mt_rand(0,1800);
}
```

Your last step of distributing the numbers to "combined" keys however will either kill a lot of randomness - or you should also take options like

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => 1 
    ) 
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => 11
        [1] => 15
        [2] => 17
    ) 
    [7] => 18 
)
```

as a valid result.

I would create an array of the desired length (`m`), and finally push each entry of the above based on `index % m`

To get your desired output you need to create another array of the desired length `m`, iterate over `n` again, pick all arrays with smallest size, (if more than 1 pick a random one from that list)
push the value.

Something like:

```
   $finalArray = array();

  for ($i=0; $i<$m;$i++){
    $finalArray[] = array(); //create empty arrays.
  }

  //push values of prior generated to the least filled array.
  foreach ($tmp_array as $key=>$value){
    $idx = findNext($finalArray);
    $finalArray[$idx][] = $value; 
  }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($finalArray);
  echo "</pre>";

  function findNext(&$array){
    $idx = null;
    $length = null;

    $i = -1;
    foreach ($array AS $var){
       $i++; 
      if ($length === null || count($var) < $length){
         $length = count($var);
         $idx = $i;
      }
    }

    return $idx;
  }
```

Note: untested, may not even run :)

Comment: Hi @dognose and thanks for your time! The values will be random with your code, but there's no guarantee that they'll be unique. And there's something wrong with the keys, they are not random.


`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 258
            [1] => 989
            [2] => 1148
            [3] => 451
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 60
            [1] => 32
            [2] => 62
        )

    ...
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = range(0, 1800);
shuffle($values);
$values = array_slice($values, 0, 8);

$keys = range(0, 1800);
shuffle($keys);
$keys = array_slice($keys, 0, 8);

$wowThatWasEasyIShouldReallyLearnToReadTheManualToBeAbleToComeUpWithTrivialStuffLikeThisMyself = array_combine($keys, $values);
var_dump($wowThatWasEasyIShouldReallyLearnToReadTheManualToBeAbleToComeUpWithTrivialStuffLikeThisMyself);
```

// OK, first part only – for “more values than keys”, go figure something out yourself.